# Confusion about length contraction of gaps in relativity

Tags: special-relativity

I am trying to understand if gaps contract in the same way as solid objects in SR and casually the answer seems to be yes, but there seems to be circumstances where this is not always true.

Consider the following thought experiment. A galactic battleship is firing shells at a rate of once per second at a velocity of $v= 0.8 \ c$ as measured relative to the ship. The gamma factor works out as $\gamma = 1/0.6 \approx 1.6666$. In the one-second time gap between between firing successive shells, the previous shell advances at a distance of $L = vt= 0.8 $ light seconds which is the spatial gap between shells.

Another observer moving at -0.8c relative to the ship sees the ship as moving at +0.8c and sees the shells as moving at $w = 2*v/(1+v^2) = 0.97561 \ c$ using relativistic velocity addition. The gamma factor that applies to the shells, is now $\gamma = 1/ \sqrt{1-w^2} = 4.55556 \ c$.

Applying the straightforward length contraction formula the gap between shells, which was originally 0.8 ls, is now $0.8/4.55556 \approx 0.1756$ ls.

However, I can look at in a different way. In the new reference frame, the cannon is now firing at a rate of once every 1.66666 seconds due to time dilation. In the time interval between two successive shells being launched, the first shell fired advances a distance of $1.66666 \times w = 1.62602$ ls. The second shell is fired after the ship advances a distance of $1.66666 \times v = 1.33333$ ls. The difference, representing the gap between shells in this reference frame, is $0.292683$ ls, which is not the same as the gap calculated using the length contraction formula.

What I am misunderstanding here? Do gaps always length transform in the same way as solid objects?

Comment: Have you drawn the relevant spacetime diagram?  And/or done the equivalent algebra?

Comment: how many dimensions are there? are the mystery stationary moving observer colinear with the shells, or like another ship passing a broadside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applying the straight forward length contraction formula the gap
> between shells, which was originally 0.8 ls, is now $0.8/4.55556 \approx 0.1756$ ls.

The $0.8\text{ ls}$ gap in the ship frame is not the proper length, it is a contracted length since the shells are moving at $0.8c$ with respect to the ship. The proper length in the frame where the shells are at rest can thus be calculated as
$$\ell_0 = \frac{0.8\text{ ls}}{\sqrt{1 - 0.8^2}}=1.333\text{ ls}.$$
You can then calculate the contracted length in the frame moving at $-0.8c$ as
$\ell_w=\sqrt{1 - w^2}\ell_0=0.293\text{ ls}.$ This is the same as the result of your second approach.

Comment: Thanks. That appears to clear things up.

Answer (score 5):

Gaps do transform the same. The Lorentz transform transforms the coordinates of one frame to the coordinates of another frame. It does not matter if there are atoms or vacuum between those coordinates.

> Applying the straight forward length contraction formula

The straight forward length contraction formula does not apply to this scenario. You need to use the Lorentz transform. The length contraction formula applies only when the worldlines are at rest in one of the frames. This has nothing to do with gaps or not.

I recommmend against teaching either the length contraction or time dilation formulas. Instructors should just teach the Lorentz transform. When the simplified formulas apply, the Lorentz transform will automatically simplify. And when they do not apply students will avoid this common mistake.

Comment: yes on the teaching, but maybe no. LT is too abstract for many noobs. If you do start with dilation/contraction, all you need to do is bring the ruler out and start wrapping knuckles while yelling, "You have got stop forgetting the relativity of simultaneity" ten times. They'll catch on.

Comment: Hi Dale, I am pretty sure the question has arisen in relation to recent discussions on the site about the Ehrenfest paradox. A common explanation of the paradox is that measuring rods rotating around the circumference are length contracted, so that gaps appear between them, but of course if you realise it is space contracting, not the rods, the idea of gaps doesn't make sense. I'd be interested in your thoughts on my recent question about it...

Comment: @MarcoOcram I am glad to take a look. I answered one of the OP’s questions on the rotation topic and I don’t think they liked my answer. I draw a strong distinction between length contraction and rotation. They are physically different.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't finish the question, so pls note in the comments if needed.

But what is wrong is what is always wrong with SR apparent contradictions: you forgot the relativity of simultaneity. When does the moving observers who is the stationary observer compare shell separation?

To figure out SR problems, step one is be clear, and follow the protocols:

The frame $S$ is stationary and fires a shell every second. No prime = stationary.

Step2 is do the Lorentz transformation. Do the Lorentz transformation. Do the Lorentz transformation.

So, you need something to transform. Ofc we're gonna fire shells on the second from the spatial origin of $S$, so the world line of the $n$th shell is:

(wait: step three is name all variables in your question if you want an answer-don't make us do it--we're calling the muzzle velocity $u$):

$$ s_n(t, x, y, z ) = (t, 0, 0, u(t-n)) $$

Wait again, you underspecified the problem. You have the stationary moving observers in the line of fire? I'll do it like that.

$$ s_n(t, x) = (t,u(t-n))$$

You can make a caveat $x>0$ if you want.

Now plot these on a space time diagram. It's gonna be a bunch of diagonal lines.

Now step 2: do the Lorentz transformation to a moving observer going at $v$. (Note how I started with a stationary observer, and then went to a moving observer? Always do this. This site is filled with noobs who start with moving observers and then it just gets confusing).

Ok, there you go: transform to $S'$.

Of course you don't need to do that, you can just draw the $x'$ axis, which is a diagonal line angles $\tan^{-1}v$ from the $x$-axis.

That is the hyperplane of simultaneity. Note it sees simultaneous shells at different times from the gunner ($S$).

Note also, that the tic marks are dilated by:

$$ U'/U = \sqrt{\frac{1+v^2}{1-v^2}} $$

So there you go.

Note that if you set $v=u$, then you have set up the classic "Lorentz contraction causes magnetic fields in a current carrying wire experiment", though one look at your space-time diagram will tell you:

"Lorentz contraction and the relativity of simultaneity cause magnetic fields in current carrying wire"